# Workspace Switcher doesn't match workspace settings

Tags: workspaces, gnome-classic

I'm having a couple of problems with the workspace switcher.

1) Whatever workspace switcher that uses my keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Alt+Arrow) doesn't match the workspace switcher settings in the panel. If I set the panel to have 2 workspaces and I try to switch with the keyboard shortcut, I end up finding that I have 8 workspaces total; four that change with the keyboard shortcut per workspace in the workspace switcher (which I can only change between with the mouse).

If I right click on the Workspace Switcher and set it to have 1 workspace, I can still use Ctrl + Alt + Arrow to switch between 4 different workspaces. It's as if I have two nested workspace managers running. If I look at workspace settings in gconf-editor, the settings don't match the ones shown if I right click on the Workspace Switcher in the panel. I want to remove one of the two competing programs, any ideas?

2) I ended up setting the Workspace Switcher to have 1 workspace, and just used the four other workspaces that show up with keyboard shortcuts to work around my first problem. However, I notice that some windows (Libre Office, pdf viewer) tend to get "dragged" with me when I switch workspaces (but only once, they never get dragged back to the original workspace I put them on).

I'm using Gnome Classic instead of Unity, I feel this has something to do with these problems but I will eat myself alive before I switch to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

open Compiz config setting Manager

click on general options

click on Desktop Size tab

see if your settings are:
    Horizontal Virtual Size =4
    Vertical Virtual Size =1
    Number of Desktops =4 (Change this to 1 and your switcher will work)

Also look at your Viewpoint Switcher.  This is the addon that will make an app drag with you when you change workspaces